# How to pull all values (even those that don't match) during a left outer join in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables (table a being 1.3 mil rows and table b being 300k rows) that I want to join on email address. However, only a 1/3rd of those addresses from table b match to table a. Ideally the output should be the length of table a in col1, col2 would be all 300k rows from table b, and col3 will say 'mapped' or 'not mapped' based on col1 & col2 being populated or not.

I want to show all the addresses from table b (even those that don't match to table a) and table a with a third col that shows they matched or they didn't. Right now it only shows as NULL.

How do I do this in SQL? Currently using a left outer join but may need to use a Full Join?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLEA.EMAIL, TABLEB.EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM "db_tablea" TABLEA
left outer JOIN
"db_tableb" TABLE B
ON TABLEA.EMAIL = TABLEB.EMAIL_ADDRESS
CASE WHEN EMAIL IS NULL AND EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL THEN 'NOT_MAPPED'
WHEN EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL THEN 'MAPPED'
ELSE 'REVIEW'
END AS MAPPED_FLAG
ORDER BY EMAIL
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*, 
    case when exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.email_address = a.email)
        then 'mapped'
        else 'not mapped'
    end as review
from tablea a
```

This generates one row for each row in the first table, with a flag that indicates whether the email exists in the second table.

One feature is that rows in the first table that have multiple matches in the second table are not "multiplied" in the resultset.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I am having trouble calling just the fields I wanted in my query instead of a.* - I am using a.email but it says its not a valid id..

Comment: @Dinho: `a` is an alias for `tablea`, so you can access any column of that table. `select a.email, case ... end as review from tablea a`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.email
    ,b.email
    ,CASE WHEN a.email = b.email THEN 'MAPPED' ELSE 'NOT MAPPED' END status
FROM
    table_a a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b b ON (a.email = b.email)
;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWn6RS8GsfRhj5oXwS3Dso/0

Comment: Appreciate the help/link!

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation that allows more insight into the records that don't match

```
select t1.email, 
       t2.email_address, 
       case when t1.email is null then 'a not mapped to b' 
            when t2.email_address is null then 'b not mapped to a' 
            else 'mutually mapped' end as mapping_flag
from table_a t1 
full join table_b t2 on t2.email_address = t1.email;
```